# Python boolean expression syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

Apparently, the following line is not valid Python syntax.

```
while (!is_int(1)):
```

How do I fix it?

Note: I don't know Python.

Comment: Assuming `is_int()` checks whether its argument is an integer, this will translate to `while False` -- or just drop the whole code block altogether.

Comment: Do you expect that `1` will ever change it's `int`edness?

Comment: There's one correct answer to this question and that's "learn Python".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean NOT is written `not` in Python:

```
while not is_int(1):
```

(Assuming you've implemented a function `is_int`.)

Answer (score -1):

Why define your own function `is_int` if you have the built-in function `isinstance`?

```
while not isinstance(1, int):
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax is:

```
while not is_int(1):
    ....
```

Where is_int can be implemented as:

```
def is_int(arg):
    return isinstance(arg, int)
```

Comment: Following http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008 type comparsion should be implemented using `isinstance(obj, int)`.